# How to pass Hive set parameters in oozie workflow

Tags: hadoop, hive, oozie

Is there anyway to pass the Hive parameter like

SET hive.exec.parallel=true;
SET hive.vectorized.execution.enabled=true;

using the oozie workflow using parameter files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the way you invoke hive query(hql) file.

If you are using hive action in the workflow, you may specify hive configuration parameter inside property tag in the configuration section or inside the hql file myscript.q

```
<workflow-app name="sample-wf" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.1">
    ...
    <action name="myfirsthivejob">
        <hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
            <job-traker>foo:9001</job-tracker>
            <name-node>bar:9000</name-node>
            <prepare>
                <delete path="${jobOutput}"/>
            </prepare>

            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>hive.exec.parallel</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>

            <script>myscript.q</script>
            <param>InputDir=/home/tucu/input-data</param>
            <param>OutputDir=${jobOutput}</param>
        </hive>
        <ok to="myotherjob"/>
        <error to="errorcleanup"/>
    </action>
    ...
</workflow-app>
```

If you use oozie shell action you can specify hive parameters as follows in the shell script.

```
hive --hiveconf "<hive queries>"
```

or

```
hive --hiveconf -f "hivequeries.hql"
```